# Django serving 500 errors for every view except root

Tags: django, apache, deployment, dreamhost

So I am trying to deploy to my production environment and am getting 500 errors for every view except the root URL: http://5buckchuck.com/

The errors appear to apache errors, not the fancy django ones:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal
>   error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server
>   administrator,
>   webmaster@5buckchuck.com and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred,
>   and anything you might have done that
>   may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
>   be available in the server error log.

per the server error logs:

> [Thu Jul 07 22:04:53 2011] [error]
>   [client my IP] Request exceeded the
>   limit of 10 internal redirects due to
>   probable configuration error. Use
>   'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase
>   the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel
>   debug' to get a backtrace.

Info:

- debugging is set to true
- I have tried syncdb, all up to date
- I have connected to the db and all looks well there
- urls.py seems to reflect all the urls in dev

I am not quite sure where to go here. Better logging would certainly help. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Per request:

`settings.py`

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
 #'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'fivebuckchuck.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
'/home/MyUserName/5buckchuck.com/fivebuckchuck/templates'

)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',

#5BC Stuff
'winerater',

#all-auth apps,
'emailconfirmation',
'uni_form',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.twitter',
'allauth.openid',
)


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'allauth.context_processors.allauth',
'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
'django.core.context_processors.media',
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

and the `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from winerater.views import *
from settings import MEDIA_ROOT
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Example:
# (r'^mobile_5BC/', include('mobile_5BC.foo.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs' 
# to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:
(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'^$', front_page),
(r'^user/(\w+)/$', user_page),
(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
(r'^login/success/$', direct_to_template,
{'template': 'front_page'}),    
#(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
 (r'^logout/$', logout_page),
  (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
   {'document_root': MEDIA_ROOT}),
  (r'^register/$', register_page),
  (r'^register/success/$', redirect_to,
   {'url': '/login/'}),
  (r'^save/$', wine_add_page),
  (r'detail/(\w+)/', wine_detail_page),
  (r'wine_image/(\w+)/$', wine_image),    
  (r'wines/([^\s]+)/$', wine_results),
  (r'review/(\w+)/$', wine_review_page),
  (r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
  (r'^accounts/profile/', front_page),
)
```

and the `passenger_wsgi.py`

```
import sys, os
INTERP = '/home/MyUserName/local/bin/python' # Is my actual username
if sys.executable != INTERP:
   os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
sys.path.append(os.getcwd()+'/fivebuckchuck')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "fivebuckchuck.settings"
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: Have you tried "LogLevel debug" yet?

Comment: <concentrates>.... <concentrates harder>... no, still can't see your code. Post it please.

Comment: Another wird thing I noticed was in the network pane, it looks like requests were being made twice:

2 requests  ❘  1.22KB transferred
/wines/reds/ 
GET
500 
text/html
675B 
283ms 
283ms0
/wines/reds/ 
GET
500 
text/html
675B 
289ms 
288ms1ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue ended up being Dreamhost writing an .htaccess file that had items for PHP in it, this subverted Django's URL reading scheme. Hope this might help other users.

Comment: How did you solve this? I assume dreamhost didn't create a .htaccess file in your directory, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your apache config for unnecessary Redirect / Rewrite / Alias lines.  Start out by removing all of them.

Comment: This is on shared hosting, so I don't think I have access to the conf file.

Answer (score 0):

This may require some back and forth to solve. My initial guess is a problem with your **passenger_wsgi.py** file. If you are not using Apache in your dev environment (using Django's *runserver* for example) then you wouldn't hit this file and thus wouldn't have problems in dev. Make sure this line is pointing to the correct Django setting's file.

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "fivebuckchuck.settings"
```

http://5buckchuck.com/media/ gives me this error:

```
An error occurred importing your passenger_wsgi.py
```

(Past tense, you've changed something and now that URL gives a "Hello World!" Python message now. Now it's an ImportError with debug traceback. Heheh, okay I'll let this answer sit for a moment.)

This may be a longshot, but take a read of [this](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/). It's James Bennett on ways to setup and load settings for Django. You could try importing your settings and feeding it to setup_environ().

Comment: Hi J, you caught me mid-stroke trying to fix this. I just installed python paste as a debugging too,l and not I get a proper error message. Namely that my app can find `uni_form`. This is weird because I can inport it from a python shell.... I will take a look at that article in just one second.

Comment: UPDATE: Sorry for the delay. I installed PyPaste directly in the app folder and the django error has gone away for Uni_form, but now I am stuck back with the 500 error trying to visit any other URL other than: 5buckchuck.com/

Per the Apache log:

[Thu Jul 14 09:39:30 2011] [error] [client 173.8.133.102] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://5buckchuck.com/

Suggestions on where to go from here? I am a bit confused.